Как организовать manifest.json в Next JS в мультиязычном сайту?
Не могу понять как организовать файл манифеста в мультиязычном сайте.
Прошу подсказать как правильно его оформить.
моя структура проекта
src
 -app
  --[lng]
    ---components
    ---about
    ---layout.tsx
    ---page.tsx

файл manifest.ts


import type { MetadataRoute } from "next";

export default function manifest(): MetadataRoute.Manifest {
  return {
    name: "Next.js App",
    short_name: "Next.js App",
    description: "Next.js App",
    start_url: "/",
    lang: "ru",
    display: "standalone",
    background_color: "#fff",
    theme_color: "#fff",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "/favicon.ico",
        sizes: "any",
        type: "image/x-icon",
      },
    ],
  };
}



